# Solr "Content" field vs "_text_" field

Tags: solr

I am wondering what is the difference between content field vs `_text_` field. I had an issue where I indexed all of my documents/pdfs, but for some reason I could not access the actual text/info in those documents/pdfs. I noticed I had no "content" field so I just created one and am currently reindexing. However, I noticed there is a `_text_` field I have that has stored=false. Do both of these fields take all the text from documents/pdfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_text_` is a field defined by default on a new Solr core (see https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/schemaless-mode.html).

The default `managed-schema` file in a new Solr core does not show anything to indicate that it is populated with anything, so I suspect it's up to you to populate it.

The `_text_` field can be used to dump a copy of all the text in the document but this is something that you have to do (either manually populating the `_text_` field or using `copyFields`.)

The fact that `_text_` is indexed but not stored means that you can search for text inside of it (because it's indexed) but you cannot fetch and display its value to the user (because it is not stored).

Comment: thanks for replying! so if I change `_text_` so that stored=true, and then reindex, I should be able to access all the contents of my documents right? like highlighting content, etc.